# AWS Codeguru review recommendation is not working

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have setup AWS code guru reviewer in my profile with a Github branch. I have created the pull request which is associated with Codeguru reviewer, but recommendation is 0 and Metered lines of code also 0. Please suggest if there is anything wrong I have done .